# YouTube Analytics API End Screen Report, how can I determine End Screen Element?

Tags: youtube-api

For an End Screens report, how can I determine which target is represented by the `end_screen_element_id` on each record?

For example: on my channel, let's say I have "Video 1" set up with two video end screen elements "Video 2" and Video 3". I want to know how many clicks at the end of "Video 1" went to "Video 2" and how many went to "Video 3".

The data returned for this report gives me a `video_id` field indicating which video was watched and an `end_screen_element_clicks` field indicating how many times a viewer clicked through to the end screen video...

...HOWEVER, the only identifier for *which video the viewer clicked through to* is an `end_screen_element_id` field, which looks like a GUID and apparently somehow refers to the full end screen element definition, and therefore presumably what video is represented by that definition.

I'm unable to find any reports or other API calls for getting detail information on that `end_screen_element_id` field, particularly which video it represents.

How can I use that field or otherwise figure out what end screen video the viewer clicked through to?

**More Information**

The data returned looks like this:
[Data returned in the End Screens report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usynk.png)

Here's a screenshot that may help explain what I'm trying to do with the data: [YouTube Analytics screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqClM.png)

The following C# code demonstrates how the report is requested:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
},
    new[] {  YouTubeReportingService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

YouTubeReportingService reportingService = new YouTubeReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME
});

// Submit a report job to obtain the latest End Screen statistics.
Job channelEndScreenJob = new Job();
channelEndScreenJob.ReportTypeId = "channel_end_screens_a1";
channelEndScreenJob.Name = JOB_NAME;

Job createdJob = 
reportingService.Jobs.Create(channelEndScreenJob).Execute();
```

A separate service retrieves the report like this:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
},
    new[] {  YouTubeReportingService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

YouTubeReportingService reportingService = new YouTubeReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME
});

// Retrieve data from jobs that were previously submitted.
ListJobsResponse jobList = reportingService.Jobs.List().Execute();

if (jobList.Jobs != null)
{
    foreach (Job job in jobList.Jobs)
    {
        ListReportsResponse reportList = reportingService.Jobs.Reports.List(job.Id).Execute();

        if (reportList.Reports != null)
        {
            foreach (Report report in reportList.Reports)
            {
                MediaResource.DownloadRequest getRequest = reportingService.Media.Download("");

                // Download the report data.
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    getRequest.MediaDownloader.Download(report.DownloadUrl, stream);
                    stream.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        // Parse report...
                        DataTable parsedReport = ReportToDataTable(reader.ReadToEnd());

                        // ...and get data on videos watched and videos clicked to.
                        foreach (DataRow row in parsedReport.Rows)
                        {
                            string videoWatched = row["video_id"].ToString();
                            string videoClickedToFromEndScreen = **WHAT???**
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing some code might make this easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Thank you @jdv, I appreciate your review and will add a code example.

Comment: Here is the relevant YouTube Analytics API documentation for this report: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-end-screens